# Assets and Matrix server error on save with high numbers of Matrix rows

Tags: matrix, assets

I had an issue on an earlier site build where entries containing a Matrix field with numbers of rows in excess of about 60 wouldn't save. The Matrix field in question contained two Assets fields, a couple of text fields and a PT Pill. I thought I had traced the issue to a problem in upgrading from Assets 1 to 2, and for various reasons ended up downgrading to 1 again as a solution.

I've now run into the same issue again on a brand new site, with fields exactly as described above, using Assets 2. It's for a photographic portfolio - the like of which I've built several times before using Assets 1 and never had this problem. What happens is that when I try to save the entry, when having gone above a certain number of rows, the browser load bar sticks, and eventually (after several minutes) I get an internal server error message.

There's no issue on entries with lower numbers of rows, and there's no issue with opening the entry for editing, only when saving.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those text fields Wygwam fields? I've had a similar issue with Wygwam fields.

Comment: No, not Wygwam fields, plain text

Answer (score 2):

I hit this recently. You need to increase the max_execution_time in php.ini. i went with 300 and this fixed it right up for me. Also make sure you have sufficient memory. I specify 128Mb+

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I raised the timeout from 60 to 300 and got the same problem. Also upped the memory limit from 128 to 512. Can't help thinking this operation shouldn't be taking 5 mins+ to execute though.

Comment: That's a bummer. Must be a different issue to what I had. As Leigh noted, definitely ping P&T. They're insanely quick to respond in my experience. Good Aluck with it and would appreciate if you can post back the solution for future reference.

Comment: Thanks, had this info back from P&T - it hasn't helped me sadly, I'm still talking with them about a solution, but it might do for someone else: "What PHP version are you running? If it's at least PHP 5.3.9, then it's a good chance you're hitting the 'max_input_var' limit, which defaults to 1000."

Answer (score 0):

In addition to increasing the memory in the php.ini as Damien_Buckley stated, you might also want to talk to the server admin, see if there's a way on his end to increase the memory or otherwise optimize the server. Otherwise, in another six or eight months, you may hit this same problem again if your site keeps expanding / adding Assets and Matrix rows.

You may also want to ping the Pixelandtonic folks about this issue - see if they can do anything on their end to make future versions run better and avoid this error. (If you haven't already, that is!)

Comment: Thanks, I'll message the hosts and p&t to see what they can do.